# Relation between 4-divergence and 3-divergence of vector on the hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

How the relation $\nabla_{a} u^{a}=D_{a} u^{a}-\epsilon v^{i} \nabla_{i} v_{j} u^{j}$ where $D_{a}$ is covariant derivate on the hypersurface

between 4-divergence and 3-divergence of the vector on the hypersurface is obtained?

Which book should I look into for hypersurfaces?

Answer (score 0):

The ambient and the intrinsic connection satisfies the relation $$ h^\kappa_\nu\nabla_\kappa X^\mu=D_\nu X^\mu-\epsilon K_{\nu\kappa}X^\kappa n^\mu, $$ where $X$ is a tangential vector field along the hypersurface, $h$ is the induced metric/projector, $K$ is the extrinsic curvature, $n$ is the unit normal with length $g_{\mu\nu}n^\mu n^\nu=\epsilon=\pm 1$.

Using $\delta^\mu_\nu=h^\mu_\nu+\epsilon n^\mu n_\nu$, the divergence is $$ \nabla_\mu X^\mu=\delta^\kappa_\mu\nabla_\kappa X^\mu=h^\kappa_\mu\nabla_\kappa X^\mu+\epsilon n^\kappa n_\mu\nabla_\kappa X^\mu \\ =D_\mu X^\mu-\epsilon K_{\mu\kappa}X^\kappa n^\mu+\epsilon n^\kappa n_\mu\nabla_\kappa X^\mu. $$

The second term vanishes because $K_{\mu\nu}n^\mu=0$. In the third term, assuming that we are actually working with a local foliation instead of just one hypersurface, and both $n$ and $X$ has been extended off the hypersurface in a way to preserve their properties for all leaves (i.e. $n$ remains normal to all leaves of the foliation and $X$ remains tangent), we have $n_\mu X^\mu=0$ even off the hypersurface.

I leave the final step to be worked out by the OP.